# Removing duplicate entries from database Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, duplicates

I've read a few "solutions" on stack overflow but none really definitely answer the question.

How do I remove duplicate data based on a few fields from the database but keeping one entry.

For example I have stored in my Database:

```
[
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Spend', 'amount' => 10.55],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Spend', 'amount' => 10.52],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Spend', 'amount' => 10.55],
]
```

and the end result id want is:

```
[
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Spend', 'amount' => 10.52],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Spend', 'amount' => 10.55],
]
```

Im not too sure how to do this because i need to check for duplicates with the same name AND amount fields, then delete all but 1.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would like to run query directly in database or using Laravel?

Comment: @VikashPathak Using laravel if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to do this Like using `DB::delete()` running raw query.

```
$affectedRow = DB::delete('DELETE t1 FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.amount = t2.amount');
```

change `table` with your actual table name.

It return the no of rows deleted.

**Another Solution:** ***Not tested!***

Here you can add your other custom queries as well!

```
// find the duplicate ids first.
$duplicateIds = DB::table("table")
                    ->selectRaw("min(id) as id")
                    ->groupBy("amount", "name")
                    ->havingRaw('count(id) > ?', [1])
                    ->pluck("id");



// Now delete and exclude those min ids.
DB::table("table")
    ->whereNotIn("id", $duplicateIds)
    ->havingRaw('count(id) > ?', [1])
    ->delete();
```

Comment: @YasminFrench let me know if it helps!

Comment: This has worked! But i have over 20k+ rows. Can i do something like `Expense::whereBetween('id', [1,100])->delete(***)`?

Comment: @YasminFrench but it won't find the duplicate.. for that you should have to get the ids of dupliated records first and then match, keep one and remove else.

Comment: @YasminFrench do you have value of `name` or `amount`field to query?

Comment: Well its a dynamic query so the name / amount would change

Comment: Then it's fine..else you can try the other solution given.. Note that is not tested. but the concept is same.

Comment: I would hash all the values and use laravel collection function `unique`.

Comment: Collection -> unique could only used to return the unique values from collection...it could not help to remove from db.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following query from Laravel or directly in database.

I assume that you have the database in the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Run the following query which will remove those duplicate data.

```
DELETE order_1 FROM tbl_order order_1, tbl_order order_2 WHERE order_1.id > order_2.id AND (order_1.name = order_2.name AND order_1.amount = order_2.amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best solution was to use `DB::delete` with a group by, something like this.

```php
DB::delete('DELETE from table WHERE id not in (
    select id from (
        select max(id) as id from table group by field, field_2
    ) as duplicates
)');
```